# List tasks where User chanded status in period

Tags: search, updatedate

How can I find all tasks where the Гser changed the status from "Waiting" to "In progress" during a certain period?
The advanced search like:

`status changed by User1 AND updated > 2023-10-08 AND updated < 2023-10-21`

shows me only tasks where the last date of updating was in this period
BUT if user1 worked on it in  my period but someone have changed status after 2023-10-21, then the tasks not in list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.